# How to copy "postRequest" from C# to python

Tags: c#, python

I wonder how to copy this code from C# (given from my friend).

```
FisHttp.HttpClientSocket fisclient = new HttpClientSocket();
fisReply = fisclient.postRequest(_fisGetUrl, context);
```

Apply to python base.

Comment: It's unclear what that code does, what FisHttp is, or what _you have already tried_ in Python (this is important; we're not a code conversion service).

Comment: You question really should be "*how do i send a Post request in python when i haven't done any research or tried anything.*" To be fair to you, you should really take this time to read the help on asking questions on stackoverflow,

Answer (score 0):

you can use request in python like this:

```
import urllib2
import json
        req = urllib2.Request("REQUEST_ADDRESS")
        req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        try:
            response = urllib2.urlopen(req, json.dumps(model))
        except:
            print "Connection To Server Error!!!!!!!!......"
        else:
            text = response.read()
```

and "model" is a dict of data